# Accessing values in a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My dictionary looks like this:

```
docScores = {0:[{u'word':2.3},{u'the':8.7},{u'if':4.1},{u'Car':1.7}],
             1:[{u'friend':1.2},{u'a':5.2},{u'you':3.8},{u'person':0.8}],
             ...
             29:[{u'yard':1.5},{u'gardening':2.8},{u'paint':3.7},{u'brush':1.6}]
            }
```

I want to sum the values of each inner dict for each list and store it in a new dict, with the new dict having key values of `{0:2.3+8.7+4.1+1.7, 1:1.2+5.2+3.8+0.8, ... etc}` i.e.

```
for x in docScores[0]: #{0:
    for x in docScores[0][0].values(): #{,2.3}.
        sum = sum+x #where sum = 0 before loop
        docSum[0] = sum
    repeat this loop for every document
```

Any variation that I have tried is giving me unexpected outputs. Can anyone give me the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Can you post what you expect the result to be for this?  do you want `{0: 2.3+8.7+4.1+1.7, 1: 1.2+5.2_3.8+0.8, ... 29: 1.5+2.8+3.7+1.6}` ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it will edit my question accordingly

Comment: This calls for one amazing list comprehension... It's a pity that I don't have time to write it now.

Comment: Why the list of `dict`s, each holding a single element? That looks like a terrible waste of memory.

Comment: @larsmans I'm still learning python and dicts have been my biggest stumbling block. I'm working on a large program and to get to the point I'm at now it was the only way I could get the values as they are. What would you recommend as an alternative that I could look into?

Comment: @adohertyd: instead of `[{u'word':2.3},{u'the':8.7}]`, I would suggest `{u'word':2.3, u'the':8.7}`. I.e., a single `dict` per document.

Comment: @larsmans is *exactly* right. What's more, instead of each integer having its own key in the dictionary, just have it as a list. So instead of a dict of lists of dicts, you'll just have a list of dicts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dict comprehension works:

```
docScores = {0:[{u'word':2.3},{u'the':8.7},{u'if':4.1},{u'Car':1.7}],
             1:[{u'friend':1.2},{u'a':5.2},{u'you':3.8},{u'person':0.8}],
             29:[{u'yard':1.5},{u'gardening':2.8},{u'paint':3.7},{u'brush':1.6}]
            }

sum_d={k:sum(d.values()[0] for d in v) for k,v in docScores.items()}

print sum_d
```

Prints:

```
{0: 16.8, 1: 11.0, 29: 9.6}
```

However, changing your data structure may be easier. You could have a dict of dicts:

```
>>> NdocScores = {0:{u'word':2.3,u'the':8.7,u'if':4.1,u'Car':1.7},
...              1:{u'friend':1.2,u'a':5.2,u'you':3.8,u'person':0.8},
...              29:{u'yard':1.5,u'gardening':2.8,u'paint':3.7,u'brush':1.6}
...             }
```

Which allows each docs data to be directly accessed:

```
>>> NdocScores[0]
{u'Car': 1.7, u'the': 8.7, u'word': 2.3, u'if': 4.1}
>>> NdocScores[0][u'Car']
1.7
>>> sum(NdocScores[1].values())
11.0

>>> NdocScores[29]
{u'gardening': 2.8, u'yard': 1.5, u'brush': 1.6, u'paint': 3.7}
```

Or, just have a list of dicts with the position in the list corresponding to the doc index:

```
>>> lofdicts=[v for k,v in NdocScores.items()]
>>> lofdicts
[{u'Car': 1.7, u'the': 8.7, u'word': 2.3, u'if': 4.1}, {u'a': 5.2, u'person': 0.8, u'you': 3.8, u'friend': 1.2}, {u'gardening': 2.8, u'yard': 1.5, u'brush': 1.6, u'paint': 3.7}]
>>> lofdicts[0]
{u'Car': 1.7, u'the': 8.7, u'word': 2.3, u'if': 4.1}
>>> sum(lofdicts[1].values())
11.0
```

Comment: Why `d[d.keys()[0]]` instead of `d.values()[0]`?

Comment: Note that this solution only works on python2.7.  prior to 2.7, dict comprehensions didn't exist.  after 2.7, `dict.values()` no longer returns an indexable object and `dict.iteritems()` no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_dict={}

docScores = {0:[{u'word':2.3},{u'the':8.7},{u'if':4.1},{u'Car':1.7}],
             1:[{u'friend':1.2},{u'a':5.2},{u'you':3.8},{u'person':0.8}],
             29:[{u'yard':1.5},{u'gardening':2.8},{u'paint':3.7},{u'brush':1.6}]
            }

for k,v in docScores.items():
    new_dict[k]=sum( sum(d.values()) for d in v )

print (new_dict) #{0: 16.8, 1: 11.0, 29: 9.6}
```

As others have mentioned, you *could* make this into a dictionary comprehension (python 2.7+):

```
new_dict = {k : sum( sum(d.values()) for d in v ) for k,v in docScores.items() }
```

But at this point I think that the comprehension is getting very difficult to comprehend (and therefore I wouldn't do it).

Also, someone should probably point out that if all your dictionary keys are sequential integers starting from 0 and going to 29, You probably shouldn't be using a dictionary to store this data -- maybe a list would be more appropriate ...

**EDIT**

using a list:

```
new_list = [sum( sum(d.values()) for d in v ) for _,v in sorted(docScores.items()) ]
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 if that's going to make a difference?

Comment: @adohertyd -- I've updated my answer to be python2 and python3 compatible.

Comment: @adohertyd -- one new update `sum(d[kk] for kk in d)` was stupid -- I don't know why I used that ...  `sum(d.values())` is much better.

Comment: thank you works great. How would I transform this to a list instead as you recommend? I'm more comfortable working with lists anyway

Comment: @adohertyd: You should generate the original data as a list rather than create it as a dict and transform it. However, `[docScores[i] for i in range(0, max(docScores.keys()) + 1)]` would do the trick.

Comment: @adohertyd -- I've updated the solution to use a list.  Note to transform a dict with your structure to a list, `[v for _,k in sorted(your_dict.items()]` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> doc_scores = {
        0: [{u'word': 2.3}, {u'the': 8.7}, {u'if': 4.1}, {u'Car': 1.7}],
        1: [{u'friend': 1.2}, {u'a': 5.2}, {u'you': 3.8}, {u'person': 0.8}],
        29: [{u'yard': 1.5}, {u'gardening': 2.8}, {u'paint': 3.7}, {u'brush': 1.6}]
}
>>> dict((k, sum(n for d in v for n in d.itervalues())) 
         for k, v in doc_scores.iteritems())
{0: 16.8, 1: 11.0, 29: 9.6}
```

If you only have one value in each of the dicts in the lists you can shorten this:

```
>>> dict((k, sum(d.values()[0] for d in v)) for k, v in doc_scores.iteritems())
{0: 16.8, 1: 11.0, 29: 9.6}
```

Answer (score 1):

And more oneline solve )

```
sum(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [d.values() for d in v for _,v in docScores.iteritems()]))
```

Comment: Opppps, I have not read the problem correctly, but this code sum all your coeffs for all structure. ))

Answer (score 0):

```
docScores = {0:[{u'word':2.3},{u'the':8.7},{u'if':4.1},{u'Car':1.7}],
             1:[{u'friend':1.2},{u'a':5.2},{u'you':3.8},{u'person':0.8}],
             2:[{u'yard':1.5},{u'gardening':2.8},{u'paint':3.7},{u'brush':1.6}]
            }


result = dict(enumerate(sum (sum(word.values()) for word in  word_list[1]) for word_list in sorted(docScores.items())  ) )
```